# Springboot: Error creating bean with name 'mongo' defined in class path resource

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot, maven

I am trying to run my local and getting below error with the pom and dependency details provided below. Getting error even after including the mongo dependencies in the pom.xml. Can someone please help on the issue.

**Issue#1** "Error creating bean with name 'mongoTemplate' defined in class path resource"

**Issue#2** "Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains compatible versions of the classes"

**ERROR**

```
Error creating bean with name 'mongoService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'mongoTemplate'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'mongoTemplate' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/mongo/MongoDatabaseFactoryDependentConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'mongoTemplate' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'mongoDatabaseFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/mongo/MongoDatabaseFactoryConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'mongoDatabaseFactory' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mongo' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/mongo/MongoAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.mongodb.client.MongoClient]: Factory method 'mongo' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.mongodb.MongoClientSettings$Builder.contextProvider(Lcom/mongodb/ContextProvider;)Lcom/mongodb/MongoClientSettings$Builder;
2021-12-27 11:16:06,664 INFO   [spring.application.name_IS_UNDEFINED] - Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2021-12-27 11:16:06,670 INFO   [spring.application.name_IS_UNDEFINED] - HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2021-12-27 11:16:06,675 INFO   [spring.application.name_IS_UNDEFINED] - HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
2021-12-27 11:16:06,700 INFO   [spring.application.name_IS_UNDEFINED] - Cache 'mongoConfig' removed from EhcacheManager.
2021-12-27 11:16:06,709 INFO   [spring.application.name_IS_UNDEFINED] - Stopping service [Tomcat]
2021-12-27 11:16:06,739 INFO   [spring.application.name_IS_UNDEFINED] - 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2021-12-27 11:16:06,768 ERROR  [spring.application.name_IS_UNDEFINED] - 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

An attempt was made to call a method that does not exist. The attempt was made from the following location:

    org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.mongodb.TraceSynchronousMongoClientSettingsBuilderCustomizer.customize(TraceSynchronousMongoClientSettingsBuilderCustomizer.java:47)

The following method did not exist:

    com.mongodb.MongoClientSettings$Builder.contextProvider(Lcom/mongodb/ContextProvider;)Lcom/mongodb/MongoClientSettings$Builder;

The calling method's class, org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.mongodb.TraceSynchronousMongoClientSettingsBuilderCustomizer, was loaded from the following location:

    jar:file:/D:/.m2/repository/org/springframework/cloud/spring-cloud-sleuth-instrumentation/3.1.0/spring-cloud-sleuth-instrumentation-3.1.0.jar!/org/springframework/cloud/sleuth/instrument/mongodb/TraceSynchronousMongoClientSettingsBuilderCustomizer.class

The called method's class, com.mongodb.MongoClientSettings$Builder, is available from the following locations:

    jar:file:/D:/.m2/repository/org/mongodb/mongo-java-driver/3.12.10/mongo-java-driver-3.12.10.jar!/com/mongodb/MongoClientSettings$Builder.class
    jar:file:/D:/.m2/repository/org/mongodb/mongodb-driver-core/4.4.0/mongodb-driver-core-4.4.0.jar!/com/mongodb/MongoClientSettings$Builder.class

The called method's class hierarchy was loaded from the following locations:

    com.mongodb.MongoClientSettings.Builder: file:/D:/.m2/repository/org/mongodb/mongo-java-driver/3.12.10/mongo-java-driver-3.12.10.jar


Action:

Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains compatible versions of the classes org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.mongodb.TraceSynchronousMongoClientSettingsBuilderCustomizer and com.mongodb.MongoClientSettings$Builder


Process finished with exit code 1
```

**POM.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.1</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>test-mongo-dependency-api</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>test-mongo-dependency-api</name>
    <description>test-mongo-dependency-api</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>8</java.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <spring.cloud-version>2021.0.0</spring.cloud-version>
    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.cloud-version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
            <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
            <version>3.12.10</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
            <artifactId>mongodb-driver-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-sleuth</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-integration</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.0</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Spring Boot 2.6.1 sets the MongoDB version to 4.4.0. Do not include dependencies for both MongoDB 3.12.10 and MongoDB 4.4.0. You already include the dependency `spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb` which transitively includes the MongoDB version compatible with the Spring Boot version.

Comment: I tried removing both dependencies MongoDB 3.12.10 and MongoDB 4.4.0, but still see the issue persists.